# php5-fpm : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) but 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 is to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, php, nginx

I want to set up PHP behind Nginx with FastCGI but I stuck  on the `sudo apt-get -f install php5-fpm`

what i've tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install php5-fpm 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-fpm : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) but 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

my source-list (this server is restricted to Ukrainian network only, no connecting to the world)

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu precise-updates universe

deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
```

Comment: Why you have precise and quantal repositories?

Comment: @Braiam yes i did...

Comment: `quantal-security main restricted` because I need php5-fpm... and `precise universe` because yandex don't have `main restricted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing repositories of different versions. You should not ever do that!

> precise universe because yandex don't have main restricted

Yandex repository is complete with `main`, `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse` in all the `precise` `precise-updates` and `precise-security` as can be seen here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After you have fixed your repositories, just do `sudo apt-get update` and it will be fine.

> quantal-security main restricted because I need php5-fpm

Precise has the package!

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5-fpm

Comment: lets say i place only `precise universe` than i can't install php5 `sudo apt-get  install php5` E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate

Comment: @dvrecmfo of course, php5 is in main repositories, you should put something like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6220331/